# Trying to connect Python 3.6 to Oracle DB with cx_oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have loaded `python 3.6` and `cx_oracle`.  I am trying to connect to an Oracle DB using a `sqlalchemy` engine.

```
sa.create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://Userid/passwd@tnsname'
```

(subbing in each needed value)

I can connect with these credentials through **SQL Developer**. 
However, Python says:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0rc1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with SQLAlchemy. See this [issue](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/27) which will provide you the information you are looking for, I believe.

Comment: Thanks Anthony!  Upgrading sqlalchemy was the answer.  I had just installed it within the last month, but it installed version 1.1.5.  I upgraded to 1.1.11 and the connection string worked fine!